# Should \Q...\E be used to escape meta character in the replacement of s///?

Tags: regex, perl

Are there any metacharacters that can appear in the replacement part of a substitution regexp, except for `\1` and `$1`? When interpolating a variable, should I use `\Q...\E`?

Example:

```
my $str = 'foo bar baz';
$str =~ s/ba/\Q$benign_user_input\E/g;
```

Comment: No, `\Q...\E` is not for escaping chars in the replacement. Replacement patterns != regex patterns.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. How can I escape the replacement? Is there a need?

Comment: Yes, you need to escape some chars in the replacement. `/` if you use `/` as a delimiter, `$` if it is followed with a digit, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I salute you for trying to avoid code injection bugs. Here's the question you must perpetually ask yourself to avoid that:

> Am I concatenating two different kinds of content together?

If the answer is yes, you have a potential problem. If the result will be used as code, that's a potential code injection bug.

Are you trying to concatenate arbitrary text with shell code? Potential code injection bug.

Are you trying to concatenate arbitrary text with SQL code? Potential code injection bug.

Are you trying to concatenate arbitrary text with HTML code? Potential code injection bug.

Are you trying to concatenate arbitrary text with a regex pattern? Potential code injection bug.

This last one is where `\Q..\E` comes in useful. It's used on the pattern side to convert text into a regex pattern that matches that text.

---

Now let's put that to the test here.

You have

```perl
my $str = 'foo bar baz';
$str =~ s/ba/$benign_user_input/g;
```

This is equivalent to

```perl
my $str = "foo " . $benign_user_input . "r " . $benign_user_input . "z";
```

We have concatenation, so we must ask ourselves

> Am I concatenating two different kinds of content together?

It's unclear what `foo bar baz` is, and it's unclear what `$benign_user_input` contains. So there is insufficient information to answer the question.

For example, this would be a code injection bug:

```perl
my $benign_user_input = "Document 1.pdf";

my $shell_cmd = 'rm -- file';

$shell_cmd =~ s/file/$benign_user_input/;
```

But maybe not this:

```perl
my $benign_user_input = "World";

my $greeting = 'Hello, name!';

$greeting =~ s/name/$benign_user_input/;
```

Comment: Thank you ikegami. If I do `s/ba/$benign_user_input/g`, should the variable be escaped? Is there any metacharacter that would get interpolated?

Comment: Note that `s/.../foo$bar/` concatenates `foo` and the value of `$bar`. So the question would have to be asked for that too. But you had just `s/.../$bar/`

Comment: I've never heard that the concatenation itself was the dangerous part, but rather how you use or allow arbitrary input. Also you wrote "concatenation" when you meant "concatenating".

Comment: @TLP 1) It's not specific to arbitrary text. Concatenating HTML with SQL? Potential code injection bug. 2) While people usually think in terms of input, the origin of the injected string doesn't really matter. 3) Injection (into a string) is literally another word for concatenation. But yes, code injection bugs are a specific case of the larger problem of using one type of data where another is expected.

Comment: Wikipedia refers to injection into a program rather than injection into a string, but that's never how it's used. For example, I've never heard of a buffer overflow attack being referred to as a code injection attack. On the flip side, saying concatenation is the sole source of code injection isn't right either. One could inject an string with a leading "-" into an array passed to `system`, for example. But concatenation covers the large majority of cases.